# Question about probability? World Population - (Question Revised)

Tags: probability, statistics

The world population is ~7 billion

Social Classes:

- x: Top .001% is ~70,000
- y: Second .01% is ~700,000
- z: Next .1% is ~7 million
- r: Rest 99.9% is ~6,993,000,000 (billion)
- p: population ~7,000,000,000

The odds of 1 person in the `Rest grp` meeting 1 person from the `Top  grp` **is it approx: 1 in 100,000 meets?**

What are the odds of 1 person in the `Rest grp` meeting **2 people** from the `Top grp`? **is it: 1 in 100,000^2 or 1 in 10,000,000,000?**

What are the odds of 1 person in the `Rest grp` meeting **2 people** from the `Top grp` on the same year?

(Assuming in a lifetime of 100 years.)

Comment: How big is the room? How do people enter it?

Comment: @Henry assume the room is infinite in size. They enter via means of teleport. Is my math correct?

Comment: your numbers must be wrong. 7 million is about .1% of 7 billion, not 0.001 %. This off by two zeroes error occurs for all of these, so i'm left questioning which value to use

Comment: @JohnJPershing Thanks for pointing that out. I will correct that. Hang on.

Comment: @JohnJPershing I changed the question. Can you give your answer. Greatly appropriated.

Comment: am i supposed to assume that they meet one person a day? if its 1 in 100,000 meets to meet a top group person, then i doubt one could meet two top group people while meeting only one person. My basic question is how often do random people meet?

Comment: @John I think you're helping me answer my own question. So if my math is correct (1 in 100,000) It means for every 100,000 people met, 1 will be in top group. So if 200,000 people are meet 2 will be in top group. So that answer is always 1 in 100,000. and always a .001% of the next person you meet being in a top group. Is this correct?

Comment: If there is replacement (you can meet the same person twice) then you are completely right.

Comment: @JohnJPershing So it would be `(p-(x+y+z))/p` if there was replacement I would have to subtract the 100,000 people on every iteration. How would that look in the formula? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If your room contains all 7 billion people, the the probability of having at least 2 people from the top group, and at least 1 from the bottom group, is 100%.

If your room contains 3 people, chosen at random with replacement, then the probability that they consist of exactly 2 people from category A, and 1 from Category B, is $$3a^2b$$ where $a$ is the fraction of the world in category $A$, and $b$ is the fraction of the world in category $B$.  The reason for the 3 is that the person from $B$ could be the first, second, or third person chosen; that is we are computing $aab+aba+baa$.

Now, technically we choose without replacement, but with the numbers involved the probability will be almost exactly the same.

Comment: So is it correct to say this: `100,000,000,000*.001%^2*99.9%`Statistically speaking you would need 100 billion people in 1 room for the odds of 1 person from rest group to be in the same room as 2 people from the top group? Is this correct? This isn't true if you put these 7 billion in a room. But I'm trying to look at it differently. I other words you would need to see 100 billion people and statistically only 2 of them will be in the top group. (So seeing the same person again counts as a see)